# Where is the JDK?

Tags: java, macos

I am mac noob using Mountain Lion 10.8.3

I have installed  a JDK.  When I do java -version I get:

```
admins-MacBook-Pro-5:~ me$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)
admins-MacBook-Pro-5:~ alexstaveley$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

But I'd like to know where the JDK is actually installed.  As in windows, I knew it was say `C:\jdk1.6`  How do I find out where it is on a mac?

Thanks.

Comment: Just enter "which java" on the command line, and it will tell you where the java executable is.

Answer (score 4):

`which` gives correct output

```
/usr/bin/java
```

which is a symlink `ls -l  /usr/bin/java`   to see where the actual binary is

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Windows, OS X does not have a "central" registry. OS X's nearest equivalent to the registry is Netinfo, but this requires authentication for modification. But like Windows, many OS X applications require a key code/serial number.

When an application is installed in OS X, it is automatically placed (or the user is prompted to drag/drop it) in the Applications folder of the hard drive (Macintosh HD > Applications).
These apps have their own per-user and system-wide properties files, (kinda like private registries), stored in human-readable files in standard locations.

What's cool is to uninstall an application, all you have to do is drag it from the Applications folder to the trash.

Hope that helps to understand a bit.

Answer (score 0):

under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

Comment: I have nothing under this directory even thou java -version returns something. I have a bunch of JDK versios in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions  any ideas why?